# Meta data for PyModule_Create

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6

In Python-2.7 the function [Py_InitModule4](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/allocation.html#c.Py_InitModule4) had an **experimental** feature.

```
PyObject* Py_InitModule4(char *name, PyMethodDef *methods, char *doc, PyObject *self, int apiver);
```

The documentation says:

> If self is non-NULL, it **will be passed to the functions** of the module
>   as their (otherwise NULL) **first parameter**. (This was added as an
>   experimental feature, and there are no known uses in the current
>   version of Python.)

Sadly they didn't ask me - I used it ;-). So the `self` argument was passed to all functions which were defined in PyMethodDef. I used this feature in my embedded environment to pass a structure to my functions. This feature doesn't seem to exist anymore in Python 3, instead `self` is now of type `PyModuleType`. Any other way how I can tunnel data to my functions, preferably without using other functions from the Python C API.

```
static PyObject * MyCustomFunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, ...)
// In Python 2 self could be set via Py_InitModule. What is the way to go in Python 3?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original implementation of the passed `self` to a C function from Python 2.x still exists in Python 3.x. But instead of a custom object, the module object, where the function lives in, gets automatically passed. However, the underlying PyCFunction still has the `m_self` member which can be replaced with another object (If done in C decref m_self before if != nullptr). This just needs to be done manually in Python 3 - after the functions got registered. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/methodobject.h#L105).

```
typedef struct {
    ...
    PyObject    *m_self; /* Passed as 'self' arg to the C func, can be NULL 
    ...
} PyCFunctionObject;
```

FYI: In Python itself you can even access it through `__self__`

```
import math
print(math.sin.__self__)  # prints: <module 'math' (built-in)
```